# How to get 3D plot for the mentioned figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a given x and y coordinates for the below figure and i want the 3D plot for the same. I have a constant width of 50 units. How should i convert the datas into 2D arrays  for the 3D plot ?
[image]
The plot will probably look something like this
[image]

Here is the code for the figure 1

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
xm=np.linspace(0,2,500)
high=2
ym=high
mean=0.03

std=0.006666
r=0.2
f=20/60
w=2*np.pi*200/60
v=2*np.pi*r*200/60
time=5
t_i=0.001
s=np.random.normal(mean,std,8)
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(12,2))
for i in s:   
    t=np.arange(0.1,time,t_i) 
    k=r+i
    c=v/k
    m=np.sqrt((k**2-(k-0.01)**2)/k)
    j=np.arcsin(m)
    x=k*(np.sin((c*t)+j))+f*t
    y=k*(np.cos((c*t)+j))
    ax.set_xlim([0.3,2])
    ax.set_ylim([y.min()-0.05,-0.1])
    reversed = False
    ind0=0
    while ind0 < len(x):
        ind1 = ind0 + 1
        if reversed:
            while ind1 < len(x) and x[ind1] <= x[ind1 - 1]:
                ind1 += 1
            ym = np.minimum(ym, np.interp(xm, x[ind0:ind1][::-1], y[ind0:ind1][::-1], left=high, right=high))
        else:
            while ind1 < len(x) and x[ind1] >= x[ind1 - 1]:
                ind1 += 1
            ym = np.minimum(ym, np.interp(xm, x[ind0:ind1], y[ind0:ind1], left=high, right=high))
        ind0 = ind1
        reversed = not reversed
ax.set_xlabel('x (µm)')
ax.set_ylabel('y (µm)')
ax.plot(xm, ym, color='r', alpha=0.5)
```